# Execute script in multiple machines using shell script by calling python script

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, shell, ssh

I have posted below question, but question was not clear. Hence I am posting again with exact requirement and example. So that this time no one get confusion.

I have Common VM (I will call it as CVM) and Two remote VM's (I will call it as RVM1 and RVM2).

from CVM I have to run python scripts in RVM1 and RVM2 Machines .

I have shell script in CVM. Below is what i am trying:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh  user@RVM1 "python -u runscript.py 5"
ssh  user@RVM2 "python -u runscript.py 10"
ssh  user@RVM1 "python -u runcommand.sh"
```

runscript.py:

```
import os
import sys
a = 10
b = 10
if sys.argv[1] == 10:
 #go back to shell script and wait to complete to shell script line (ssh  user@RVM1 "python -u runcommand.sh")
c = a + b
print c
```

Is this possible? if yes please help me how achieve this

If this is not possible, how can i achieve this, During execution in RVM2 if sys.argv[1] == 10, then it should jump to RVM1 Machine and execute command. Again come back and resume remaining script in RVM2.

Note: RVM1 and RVM2 Does not have access. Only CVM has access to RVM1 and RVM2

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear, but try:

```
if sys.argv[1] == 10:
  sys.exit(0)
```